# Transform a non-regular language into a regular one using sort

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Is there a way where sort turns a non regular language into a regular one.
What I mean by sort is this:
Consider the language $L =$ { $bac, cbca, acbb$}. $sort(L) = $ {$abc, abcc, abbc$} respectively.
If there is, do you have an example. If not can you provide a proof if you can.

Comment: Can you define the operator in more precise terms, do you mean writing all zeroes before ones and writing all as before bs before cs etc?

Comment: There is no order *within* a set.

Comment: @Anonymous please edit the question to include what sort means instead of describing it in a comment

Comment: @Russel. I reformulated my question.

Comment: Sort may also do the opposite: changing a regular language into a nonregular one: from $(abc)^*$ into $\{a^nb^nc^n\mid n\ge 0 \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the class of all non-regular languages is not closed under sort. For example take the language $L=\{a^nba^n\}$. It is clearly not regular (by the pumping lemma). However, $sort(L)$ is the language defined by even many $a$s and then a $b$. This language is clearly regular.